# Reinstall Ubuntu on dual system with /boot and sda1(boot windows10)

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I want to reinstall ubuntu 16.04.03 to my current dual system.

I have following partitions on my disk:

- */dev/sda1* , **boot Wins10**
- */dev/sda2* , Wins10
- */dev/sda3*, Swap
- */dev/sda4*, **/boot**
- */dev/sda5*, /var
- */dev/sda6*, /tmp
- */dev/sda7*, /
- */dev/sda8*, /home

### 1. Try, using Ubuntu liveCD and OS-Uninstaller

#### For people want to know what happened in details:

Insert liveCD and remember to uninstall nvidia driver before because they will blacklist nouveau driver(if when you boot liveCD, it gives you black screen with acpi error and nouveau's fifo messages). When you see the purple page press any keys to select language and then Press F6 select nomodeset.

Select "Try Ubuntu without installation", install OS-Uninstaller.

#### OS-Uninstaller does not work for me, because when I open the software, there are only 2 entries:

- Windows 10(boot) (sda1)
- Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS (sda8) ?? Why sda8? sda8 is /home of Ubuntu 16.04.01;LiveCD is 16.04.03.

But I need to uninstall 16.04.01, so this entry is not recognised at all.

This does not help.

### 2. Try, using Wins10 LiveCD,any recommends?

Going to try now to follow this link and see what will happend...

> Boot your system using windows installation CD
>
> Go to "repair your system";

Use command prompt type

> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> exit

But before, since I have /boot, what should I notice here? Beside, from *1.Try*, sda1 seems like overweight /boot? Could anyone tell me how to balance /boot and /sda1? And the relation between /boot, /sda1 with bootloader?

Best,
Yumin

Comment: In your case I would boot from the linux cd and start a live system to examine the exact layout of your hard disk with fdisk or gpart (if applicable). Normally Windows preinstalled PCs have a hidden system partition for recovery, so I can not deduce if sda1 holds this  hidden windows partition or the typical linux boot partition. Therefore we need to know the whole partiion scheme. If you can post the output of fdisk / gpart maybe we can advice you further.

Comment: I have this hidden partition for wins10

Comment: As far as I know, `/dev/sda4` is **ALWAYS** either primary partition or extended wrapper.

Comment: I don't understand that....

Comment: Please confirm: you want to reinstall your ubuntu os and keep the (original) windows installation. Question can you still boot into either OS Windows and Ubuntu? Are there any pressing reasons why you have to uninstall ubuntu ffirst?